# What does "Dale calor primo" mean?

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos

I have heard this expression sometimes. For instance, when two friends are going to play something, first one says to the second: "Dale calor primo!". What does it mean?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps it means to burn whatever they are going to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dale calor primo` it's usually used in a very informal way, normally singed in songs (reggaeton or similar).

The sentence is composed for two parts:

- The first one, `dale calor`; translated as a `Come on!`, `give me the power` or similar. In your sentence, it means `go ahead` or `do something quickly`. Literally the sentence means: give me heat.
- The second part, `primo`: it's a very colloquial way to refer someone. It could be translated as a `baby`, `guy` or `lad` in english. Literally it is translated as a cousin.

As you can se, it is a very informal way to speak, so it must be taken very carefully this kind of sentences when you translate them, because it depends in the context heavily.

Hope it helped!

Comment: De nada! (You're welcome) @bigdestroyer

Answer (score 3):

"Dar calor" would mean to "go ahead with certain emphasis" with whatever affair they are involved in.
For example when driving, "dale calor" can translate to something like "Floor the gas pedal"

Comment: Plus I would guess this was heard in Andalusia, where *primo* is a usual way to refer to a close friend.

Comment: Yeah, I guess Andalusians use it more often than us people from the north. Also, gitanos usually refer to each other as "primos" and non-gitano people are starting to use the word in a way to express closeness as well.

Comment: Gitano == Gypsy; //true` Deal with It